# Django redirect invalid form to same page with GET variables

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django view which corresponds to a URL like this:

```
<my_site>/project_info/?pitched=true
```

I validate the form for this page the normal way:

```
form = ProjectInfoForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    # handle form
    ...
```

But when the form is returned with errors it ends up at the same page without the URL (obviously):

```
<my_site>/project_info/
```

I don't really want to changed the pitched=true parameter to a captured URL parameter. What is the best way to redirect, considering I can't know if the page had this GET variable or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does the HTML in your template look like? Try setting the `action` attribute on your form to `""` (it should preserve your variables), like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

The `action=""` trick works. If you want to be sure, you can do something like

```
<form action="{% if request.GET.pitched %}?pitched={{ request.GET.pitched }}{% endif %}" method="post">
```